# Fade in an image by setting opacity

Tags: svg

I need to fade in an image thats invisible for the first 2 seconds of the animation.

This is what I have rigth now:

```
     <image x="40%" y="40%" width="30%" height="30%" id="img2"
   opacity="1"

   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
     xlink:href="img/2dugs.jpg" >
     <animate attributeName="opacity" 
   attributeType="CSS" 
   begin="2s" dur="2s" from="0" to="1" 
   repeatCount="1" />

     </image>
```

With this code the image is visible right at the start of the the animation, which I don't want. If I set  opacity="0" the start is fine: the image is not disolayed for the first 2 seconds , fades in during 2 seconds but at the end gets invisible again.

How do I get an animation that: has the image invisible for the first 2 seconds, then fades in during 2 seconds and then stays visible?

Answer (score 3):

Add `fill="freeze"` to the `<animate>` tag and make `<image ... opacity="0">`.